# Parameter Intellicense

Tags: parameters, intellisense

I have a  Insert Query function which has 23 parameters.

VS intellicence show 18 parameters but does not show after 18th parameter.

Do you know why and how can I fix it ?

I have Visual Studio 2013 and Update 4.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ok I found solution ;

https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

use this!